# fitting text in to cells

Tags: tables, fit

I have a table with 22 columns and 5 rows, I have tried `\small`   and chnge it vertically but it did not work just a part can be seen how to fix it might be make text more smaller or somthing so that it could work I have tried to change cells size also but not working here is my code

`\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>
  {\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  \begin{table} [!htbp]
  \small
  \centering 
  \begin{sideways}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline Summghtyary   & Bh &C  &Dyh    &Ei &F  &G  &H  &I& J&  K&f L&  Mk  &N& O   &P

  & Q   &Rr &S  &Ty &Uh&    V&  Wj \\
  \hline  cc.CR (\%) & 52.75    &52.75  &21.25  &21.25  &55.02& 55.05&  63.85&

  67.58&    85.45&  85.85&  62.50&  62.50&  76.54&  60.08&  55.05 & 65.04&

  60.00&    57.50&  56.25   &60.00& 63.75&  65.00\\
  \hline  fgrt CR (\%)  & 57.94 &35.25& 48.66   &47.43& 49.73&  55.29&  37.53&

  52.94&    39.04&  47.59&  33.16   &38.50& 61.50&  38.50   &28.88&  53.36& 
  24.06&    23.43&  33.76&  43.32&  45.66&  55.87 \\

  \hline Avtgrayhe CR   (\%)   & 55.85  &47.02& 54.96&  59.34&  55.37   &55.15& 
  50.59&    60.22&  45.90&  55.17&  47.83&  55.50&  65.05&  49.55&  41.94

  &53.36&   48.03&  25.57&  44.78&  51.65&  56.51&  58.84 \\
  \hline  Rbhk  & 5 &   7 & 6&  13& 9   &18&    11& 2   &19 &8& 16& 18  &1& 17& 
  21 &  7 &20&  29& 19& 17& 4&  3\\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{sideways}
  \caption{blah balabalalalalalzl}
  \label{table:10}
   \end{table}`

```
 By the way just a part of my table is displayed and the title does not even appear :(
```

edited 1 : here is the table am talking about in the comments I would like to like in this table so that my values could be fiitted for this table it s too long I could not make a full capture but it s okey [image: how to do to make my cells as in this table]
Thank you for your time and consideration..

Comment: Why don't you swap rows and columns?

Comment: @Bernard it has to be in such form I can not  :( am obliget to do so  I have added a figure ( to the question which include table more complicated and fit the cells they make  text in cells more small or I do not know how to get table like in the photo ( am talking about the text fiiting not content or table form ) see the figure I joined ps

Comment: please extend your code snipped to small but complete document. We need to know your page layout ... anyway, if you exploit full (A4) paper height, then in average each column width is only 297/22 mm, so your obligation can be (partly) achieved if you use A3 page :( or use not readable small font (read: unusable table). better approach is consider *Bernard* comment.

Comment: What is the layout of your document (paper size, margins, &c.) and *why* can't you swap rows and columns? I can make the table fit the page, playing `tabcolsep` and typing the text in `\scriptsize` which is almost unreadable. In my my opinion, less than `\footnotesize` is not sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the separation between the columns and decrease the font size even further.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \scriptsize
  \centering 
  \begin{sideways}
    \begin{tabular}{*{23}{|@{}c@{}}|}
      \hline Summghtyary         & Bh    & C     & Dyh   & Ei    & F     & G     & H     & I     & J     & K     & f L   & Mk    & N     & O     & P     & Q     & Rr    & S     & Ty    & Uh    & V     & Wj    \\
      \hline cc.CR (\%)          & 52.75 & 52.75 & 21.25 & 21.25 & 55.02 & 55.05 & 63.85 & 67.58 & 85.45 & 85.85 & 62.50 & 62.50 & 76.54 & 60.08 & 55.05 & 65.04 & 60.00 & 57.50 & 56.25 & 60.00 & 63.75 & 65.00 \\
      \hline fgrt CR (\%)        & 57.94 & 35.25 & 48.66 & 47.43 & 49.73 & 55.29 & 37.53 & 52.94 & 39.04 & 47.59 & 33.16 & 38.50 & 61.50 & 38.50 & 28.88 & 53.36 & 24.06 & 23.43 & 33.76 & 43.32 & 45.66 & 55.87 \\
      \hline Avtgrayhe CR   (\%) & 55.85 & 47.02 & 54.96 & 59.34 & 55.37 & 55.15 & 50.59 & 60.22 & 45.90 & 55.17 & 47.83 & 55.50 & 65.05 & 49.55 & 41.94 & 53.36 & 48.03 & 25.57 & 44.78 & 51.65 & 56.51 & 58.84 \\
      \hline Rbhk                & 5     & 7     & 6     & 13    & 9     & 18    & 11    & 2     & 19    & 8     & 16    & 18    & 1     & 17    & 21    & 7     & 20    & 29    & 19    & 17    & 4     & 3     \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{sideways}
  \caption{blah balabalalalalalzl}
  \label{table:10}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is it ! thank you ! this is what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say put yourself in place of your readers, would you like to read that text? Of course, NO. Typography is all about readability. I suggest reformatting the table and no one would blame you for doing the right thing. There are much better refinements to the following setup, but the idea is now clearer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htbp]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{ |*6{c|} }\hline
Summghtyary &   cc.CR (\%)  &   fgrt CR (\%)    &   Avtgrayhe CR (\%)   &   Rbhk    \\ \hline
Bh  &   52.75   &   57.94   &   55.85   &   5   \\ \hline
C   &   52.75   &   35.25   &   47.02   &   7   \\ \hline
Dyh &   21.25   &   48.66   &   54.96   &   6   \\ \hline
Ei  &   21.25   &   47.43   &   59.34   &   13  \\ \hline
F   &   55.02   &   49.73   &   55.37   &   9   \\ \hline
G   &   55.05   &   55.29   &   55.15   &   18  \\ \hline
H   &   63.85   &   37.53   &   50.59   &   11  \\ \hline
I   &   67.58   &   52.94   &   60.22   &   2   \\ \hline
J   &   85.45   &   39.04   &   45.9    &   19  \\ \hline
K   &   85.85   &   47.59   &   55.17   &   8   \\ \hline
fL  &   62.5    &   33.16   &   47.83   &   16  \\ \hline
Mk  &   62.5    &   38.5    &   55.5    &   18  \\ \hline
N   &   76.54   &   61.5    &   65.05   &   1   \\ \hline
O   &   60.08   &   38.5    &   49.55   &   17  \\ \hline
P   &   55.05   &   28.88   &   41.94   &   21  \\ \hline
Q   &   65.04   &   53.36   &   53.36   &   7   \\ \hline
Rr  &   60      &   24.06   &   48.03   &   20  \\ \hline
S   &   57.5    &   23.43   &   25.57   &   29  \\ \hline
Ty  &   56.25   &   33.76   &   44.78   &   19  \\ \hline
Uh  &   60      &   43.32   &   51.65   &   17  \\ \hline
V   &   63.75   &   45.66   &   56.51   &   4   \\ \hline
Wj  &   65      &   55.87   &   58.84   &   3   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{blah balabalalalalalzl}
\label{table:10}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Now have a look at this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!htbp]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{}c
                   S[table-format=2.2]
                   S[table-format=2.2]
                   S[table-format=2.2]
                   S[table-format=2.0]@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Summghtyary}    &   \textbf{cc.CR}  &   \textbf{fgrt CR}    &   \textbf{Avtgrayhe}  &   \textbf{Rbhk}   \\
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(\%)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{(\%)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{CR (\%)}}   \\ \midrule
Bh& 52.75   &   57.94   &   55.85   &   5   \\ 
C   &   52.75   &   35.25   &   47.02   &   7   \\ 
Dyh&    21.25   &   48.66   &   54.96   &   6   \\ 
Ei& 21.25   &   47.43   &   59.34   &   13  \\ 
F   &   55.02   &   49.73   &   55.37   &   9   \\ 
G   &   55.05   &   55.29   &   55.15   &   18  \\ 
H   &   63.85   &   37.53   &   50.59   &   11  \\ 
I   &   67.58   &   52.94   &   60.22   &   2   \\ 
J   &   85.45   &   39.04   &   45.9    &   19  \\ 
K   &   85.85   &   47.59   &   55.17   &   8   \\ 
fL& 62.5    &   33.16   &   47.83   &   16  \\ 
Mk& 62.5    &   38.5    &   55.5    &   18  \\ 
N   &   76.54   &   61.5    &   65.05   &   1   \\ 
O   &   60.08   &   38.5    &   49.55   &   17  \\ 
P   &   55.05   &   28.88   &   41.94   &   21  \\ 
Q   &   65.04   &   53.36   &   53.36   &   7   \\ 
Rr& 60    & 24.06   &   48.03   &   20  \\ 
S   &   57.5    &   23.43   &   25.57   &   29  \\ 
Ty& 56.25   &   33.76   &   44.78   &   19  \\ 
Uh& 60  &   43.32   &   51.65   &   17  \\ 
V   &   63.75   &   45.66   &   56.51   &   4   \\ 
Wj& 65  &   55.87   &   58.84   &   3   \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blah balabalalalalalzl}
\label{table:10}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Edit:**

Here is one way for splitting the table while still being highly readable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\MC}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand{\ML}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\bfseries#1}}
\begin{table} [!htbp]
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *8{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
\toprule
  \ML{Summghtyary}  &\MC{Bh}&\MC{C} &\MC{Dyh}&\MC{Ei} &\MC{F} &\MC{G} & \MC{H}&\MC{I} \\ \midrule
  cc.CR (\%)        & 52.75 & 52.75 & 21.25 & 21.25   & 55.02 & 55.05 & 63.85 & 67.58 \\
  fgrt CR (\%)      & 57.94 & 35.25 & 48.66 & 47.43   & 49.73 & 55.29 & 37.53 & 52.94 \\
  Avtgrayhe CR (\%) & 55.85 & 47.02 & 54.96 &   59.34 & 55.37 & 55.15 & 50.59 & 60.22 \\
  Rbhk              &     5 &    7  & 6     &   13    &  9    & 18    & 11    & 2     \\ \addlinespace
%\end{tabular}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}l *8{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
\toprule
  \ML{Summghtyary}  &\MC{J} & \MC{K}&\MC{f L}&\MC{Mk}&\MC{N}&\MC{O} &\MC{P} &\MC{Q} \\ \midrule
  cc.CR (\%)        & 85.45 & 85.85 & 62.50 & 62.50 & 76.54 & 60.08 & 55.05 & 65.04 \\
  fgrt CR (\%)      & 39.04 & 47.59 & 33.16 & 38.50 & 61.50 & 38.50 & 28.88 & 53.36 \\
  Avtgrayhe CR (\%) & 45.90 & 55.17 & 47.83 & 55.50 & 65.05 & 49.55 & 41.94 & 53.36 \\
  Rbhk              & 19    & 8     & 16    & 18    & 1     & 17    & 21    &   7   \\ \addlinespace
%\end{tabular}
%\begin{tabular}{@{}l *8{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}} 
\toprule
  \ML{Summghtyary}  &\MC{Rr}&\MC{S} &\MC{Ty}&\MC{Uh}&\MC{V} &\MC{Wj}& & \\ \midrule
  cc.CR (\%)        & 60.00 & 57.50 & 56.25 & 60.00 & 63.75 & 65.00 & & \\  
  fgrt CR (\%)      & 24.06 & 23.43 & 33.76 & 43.32 & 45.66 & 55.87 & & \\ 
  Avtgrayhe CR (\%) & 48.03 & 25.57 & 44.78 & 51.65 & 56.51 & 58.84 & & \\  
  Rbhk              & 20    & 29    & 19    & 17    & 4     & 3     & & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{blah balabalalalalalzl}
\label{table:10}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: it s okey @AboAmmar so you think that it could not displayed otherwise for example  as in the table I find ( they make small the text and display it without problm although it was more large and complicated than mine

Comment: @magda : No, keeping your audience rotating their heads will not give you any advantage. Simplicity, clarity, and conciseness are more engaging for your readers, you don't want to loose them, do you?

Comment: yeah but am supposed to keep the same form of my tables, and I have a lot which are done in this case I have to change all the other it not good at all :( what about keep it as I want to have horizontally  and split it into part !!! can you help because it s the only large table I want to fix not correct the whole others since alll of them have to be in the same form .. and this is the only large one , so divide it in to part !

Comment: Yes, you can split it, I'll come back in a while it's time for Sohoor now.

Comment: @magda, you are not consistent: first refuse *Bernard* comment as not acceptable, than you accept answer which essentially elaborate *Bernard's*  comment, than again complain that this solution is not acceptable ... now I'm confused, what you like to have (I'm inclined to suggest that  your question as unclear). For sure writing document whit huge tables is (very) demanding task and require deliberate decisions :)

Comment: @Zarko  I have voted for bernard suggestion also and I consider the effort elaborated by Ammar ( but as I said this not what I have to do for me it s okey more clear , simple way etc etc but am obliged so I am searching again a way to do it as the figure I joined since it exists there is away BUT I consider and appreciate all the efforts of all of you since you are triying to help me am not an expert and new on latex and since I find the figure I joined which include what I want to do I try and try .. am soory if you have misunderstand this

Comment: @AboAmmar, I liked second solution (I prepare similar answer, but from OP comments follows, that such solution is not what (s)he looking for), however I would add after each forth or fifth row `\addlinespace` which to my opinion make table better readable.

Comment: Thank you for both of you ( I appreciate your efforts ) :) @Zarko and Abou ammar ( by the way it is  just "she" :) ) ( waiting for yours I mean your answer ^^ :) )

Comment: @magda : Please see my edit for a possibility of splitting the table, while still being highly readable.

Comment: @AboAmmar thank you ammar :) it a great work as well :) and look readable (y)